# Escaping characters in Makefiles 'addprefix'

Tags: makefile

I have a list of libraries:

```
lib_paths := dir1 dir2 dir3
```

that I would like to add to my rpath via

```
LDFLAGS += (addprefix -Wl,-rpath,$(lib_paths))
```

Of course, this fails because `,` is the delimiter to the `addprefix` function in Makefiles. How can I escape the comma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put it in a variable.  Make will break arguments on commas *before* it expands them, so:

```
comma = ,

LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Wl$(comma)-rpath,$(lib_paths))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `-Wl,-rpath` is just the short variant of `-Xlinker -rpath=`:

```
LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xlinker -rpath=,$(lib_paths))
```